# AWS Ubuntu 14.04 /etc/rc.local does not work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have launched a fresh instance of: Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (PV), SSD Volume Type

Once the instance launches, I ssh into the server, and using the following command:

```
sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```

edit the rc.local to look like:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

mkdir ~/hello

exit 0
```

I save the file and logout of the ssh session. Then from the AWS online management console, I stop then start my instance:

[image]

However, when I ssh back into my server, I do not see a hello folder in the ~/ directory. rc.local is green which means it is executable, and my command is quite simple so I don't think the command is failing or anything.

So is there any way to have certain commands run every time an AWS Ubuntu 14.04 instance is started?

Comment: You'll need to specify the full path for the folder, `mkdir /home/ubuntu/hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chosen test is simple enough, but not well-chosen.

`~/` is the home directory of the current user.

The current user is not "ubuntu" when `/etc/rc.local` is running.  The current user is "root."  So `~/`, if it refers to anything, will not refer to `/home/ubuntu`.  More likely, you will find your new folder at `/root/hello`.

As noted in comments, you'd need to use the full path to get the desired outcome.